# PhpStorm Settings Repository selective sharing

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've recently given it another go to PhpStorm's Settings Repository feature in order to share the code style, file templates, live templates, etc among all members of my team.

It seems to work fine, however it syncs *everything*, including things I don't want to share, like the color scheme for example - each member of the group has their own preferences for colors, and we agree to not agree in one scheme for all of us...

So, is there any way to select the things you want to share?
I've been digging around the settings and the docs and I can't find any solution...

Comment: Partially related/FYI: Since 2018.1 they offer "IDE Settings Sync" plugin .. but it's linked to your JB account (data stored there) .. so it should be about that user only. P.S. Added few relevant in my opinion tags -- may help with question discovery a bit.

Comment: Other than that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135510 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178601 . **P.S.** There was suggestion to use `.gitignore` file to control such stuff -- see if it will work for you.